# JavaScript create second event from the first event

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to create second event from a button that i have created from the first event. i don't know how to grab the button with an id `btn_event_2` and save it into variable like i just did on the first event, so i cant create an event listener on the second button. Any suggest, thanks.

```js
let btnEvent1 = document.getElementById("btn_event_1");
let sectionA = document.getElementById("eventDemo");

function createElements(){
  let newHeader = document.createElement("h1");
  let newButton = document.createElement("button");
  let newHeaderContent = document.createTextNode("Hello World 2");
  let newButtonContent = document.createTextNode("click me");
  newHeader.appendChild(newHeaderContent);
  newButton.appendChild(newButtonContent);
  newButton.setAttribute("type", "button");
  newButton.setAttribute("id", "btn_event_2");
  sectionA.appendChild(newHeader);
  sectionA.appendChild(newButton);
}

btnEvent1.addEventListener("click", function(){
createElements();
});
```

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
            <title>Event Demo 3</title>
        </head>
    
        <body>
            <section id="eventDemo">
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
                <button type="button" id="btn_event_1">click me</button>
            </section>
        </body>
    
        <script src="demoEvent.js"></script>
    </html>
```

Comment: But but ... You already have a reference to the newly-created button in `createElements` function – `newButton`. Just add the eventlistener to the button inside the function.

Comment: you can attach an event listener to the the new button using `addEventListener("click", callback)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple use addEventListener for new created button like you do already initial.

```js
let btnEvent1 = document.getElementById("btn_event_1");
let sectionA = document.getElementById("eventDemo");

let counter = 1;

function createElements() {
  let newHeader = document.createElement("h1");
  let newButton = document.createElement("button");
  let newHeaderContent = document.createTextNode("Hello World " + counter );
  let newButtonContent = document.createTextNode("click me");
  newHeader.appendChild(newHeaderContent);
  newButton.appendChild(newButtonContent);
  newButton.setAttribute("type", "button");
  // Important update: id value always come with different data
  newButton.setAttribute("id", "btn_event_" + counter);
  newButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
    createElements();
  });
  sectionA.appendChild(newHeader);
  sectionA.appendChild(newButton);
  counter++
}

btnEvent1.addEventListener("click", function(){
createElements();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
            <title>Event Demo 3</title>
            <style>
              h1 {
                color: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
                background: #6e6e6e;
                text-shadow: 3px 2px 3px rgba(255,255,255,.2);
              }
              button {
                -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px 5px #000000; 
                box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px 5px #000000;
                border: 5px solid #1C6EA4;
                border-radius: 40px 39px 40px 40px;
              }
            </style>
        </head>
    
        <body>
            <section id="eventDemo">
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
                <button type="button" id="btn_event_1">click me</button>
            </section>
        </body>
    
        <script src="demoEvent.js"></script>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply attach an event-listener to the newbutton since you already have a reference to the newbutton in the `createElement` function.

```
let btnEvent1 = document.getElementById("btn_event_1");
let sectionA = document.getElementById("eventDemo");

function createElements() {
  let newHeader = document.createElement("h1");
  let newButton = document.createElement("button");
  let newHeaderContent = document.createTextNode("Hello World 2");
  let newButtonContent = document.createTextNode("click me");
  newHeader.appendChild(newHeaderContent);
  newButton.appendChild(newButtonContent);
  newButton.setAttribute("type", "button");
  newButton.setAttribute("id", "btn_event_2");
  sectionA.appendChild(newHeader);
  sectionA.appendChild(newButton);

  newButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log('new button clicked')
  });
}

btnEvent1.addEventListener("click", function() {
  createElements();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best suitable way to do is use `JavaScript event delegation`
u create an add eventlistner depend on your event and assign a function
inside this function u will chekck your button id if its match then you will do the rest

```js
let btnEvent1 = document.getElementById("btn_event_1");
let sectionA = document.getElementById("eventDemo");

function createElements(){
    let newHeader = document.createElement("h1");
    let newButton = document.createElement("button");
    let newHeaderContent = document.createTextNode("Hello World 2");
    let newButtonContent = document.createTextNode("click me");
    newHeader.appendChild(newHeaderContent);
    newButton.appendChild(newButtonContent);
    newButton.setAttribute("type", "button");
    newButton.setAttribute("id", "btn_event_2");
    sectionA.appendChild(newHeader);
    sectionA.appendChild(newButton);
}

btnEvent1.addEventListener("click", function(){
    createElements();
});

document.addEventListener('click',clickEventTwo)
function clickEventTwo(e) {
      if(e.target && e.target.id == 'btn_event_2') {
        alert('two')
      }
}
```

```html
 <section id="eventDemo">
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      <button type="button" id="btn_event_1">click me</button>
  </section>
```